# What's the formula for the range of enchantment values on an item?

Tags: diablo-iii

I often try to sell "powerful" rare items on the auction house.  I generally look for items that have high numbers for primary stats.  For instance, if I'm playing a dexterity-focused character, and I find something with no dexterity, but +50 intelligence, I might opt to sell that on the auction house.

However, I really have no idea what the valid range for these enchantments is.  I'd like to figure out when I'm actually holding something that is above average, versus just sort of guessing.  It strikes me that the more "awesome" a rare item's enchantments are, the higher I should try to price it on the auction house.  It would also be useful for sorting the "resaleable" rares from the vendor trash items.

I know, for instance, that there are minimum item levels for certain enchantments altogether (ie, nothing below 15 has sockets, and +resist gear doesn't show up until Nightmare levels).  However, as item levels increase, does the valid range for the enchantment also increase?  What's the formula?

Comment: Affixes can have the same name but be of different values. At this point, I think we'll have to wait until the next patch adds iLvls to items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is to consult various datamining sites.

Item affix/enchantment values are determined by the tier of the item. In your example (dexterity), if you have a Tier 6 item, it can have the "of Cruelty" suffix for 45-53 dexterity. But if it's a tier 11 item, "of Cruelty" can mean 92-101 dexterity.

Here is a list of affixes by tier, but it may be out of date: http://www.diablofans.com/topic/41045-spoiler-diablo-iii-item-affixes/#entry863906

But like I said, the easiest way is to use a datamining site like d3db.com. For example let's say you found a magical Stiletto. You can look that up on the site: http://d3db.com/item/i/stiletto?recipe=205208

From here you can see in the Affixes table what the possible values for each affix are.

Comment: I've found d3db sometimes has mistakes, but it's quite good, regardless.  For ranges of base armor and damage, check the official game guide (eg. https://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/darkblade)