# Diablo III affix range list?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What is the cap for equipment modifiers?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70529/what-is-the-cap-for-equipment-modifiers)
>   [What's the formula for the range of enchantment values on an item?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70994/whats-the-formula-for-the-range-of-enchantment-values-on-an-item)

So, I thought this would (should) be easy to find, but I've had little luck thus far. I am looking for a list of affix (stat) ranges for arbitrary iLvl gear.  Of course you can [go here](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/) to find a list of all base gear, but no mention of affix (or base dps) ranges can be found.

It would be handy to know how well an item is rolled, but I've had no luck so far.  I search here and looked through the first ten pages of results, but I didn't come up with anything, and there are about 171 total threads with the D3 tag.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are 1750 questions with the [tag:diablo-3] tag.  The problem is *finding* the question you're looking for.

Comment: @fbueckert: I figured this would be a dupe, but as you say, not always easy to find. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that will help you:

http://www.diablofans.com/topic/41045-spoiler-diablo-iii-item-affixes/

Comment: ...and it was posted on the very site I spend a ton of time on... thank you sir.  Will accept in 9 minutes

Comment: Do you know what the "tier" means in that list? E.g. what type of item can have a tier 9 magic property?

Comment: @Alderath accoring to that topic: https://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5590646579?page=1 a `tier` is a item quality, sort of like item level. `ilvl 63` = `Tier 16`, `ilvl 62` = `Tier 15`, `ilvl 61` = `Tier 14`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

http://d3inferno.com/